# Eclipse jump to end of scope/method with keyboard shortcut

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut

Is is possible to jump to the end of a scope such as a method, loop, if statement, switch statement...etc with a keyboard shortcut?

I know this is possible with <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, but it only goes to the beginning of the closing curly brace, and not over it.  For example:

This is my code.

```
if (x < 10) {
    System.out.println("X is less than ten.");| //my cursor is '|'
}
```

When I press `control+shift+P` my cursor jumps here:

```
if (x < 10) {
    System.out.println("X is less than ten.");
|}   //my cursor is '|'
```

But I want it to go here.

```
if (x < 10) {
    System.out.println("X is less than ten.");
}|   //my cursor is '|'
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I was searching for Control + shift + p shortcut and found it in your question instead of answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your keys seemed to be mapped differently than my keys, but look in the Preferences (General --> Keys) to see exactly what commands are available for your version of Eclipse and OS.  I think the closest command to what you're looking for is Run to Line (where you have to point to the line with the closing curly bracket).